# azure function http trigger inputting cosmos db document

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Referring to this [azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#input---javascript-example) 
and this [using parameters from http trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#input---javascript-example-2)

It refers specifically to

```
 "id" : "{queueTrigger_payload_property}",
 "partitionKey": "{queueTrigger_payload_property}",
```

If I have an javascript function, an http Trigger which provides a JSON packet in the body. How do I use the Azure cosmos db bindings to get a document using the binding to pass the http json value to the cosmos db query?

I expect similar to this :

```
"sqlQuery": "SELECT * from c where c.departmentId = {departmentId}",
```

except that the `{departmentId}` should be a property from the `httptrigger` (named req) ?

thus the function.json looks like this:

```
{
       "authLevel": "function",
       "type": "httpTrigger",
       "direction": "in",
       "name": "req"
     }, {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "mydb",
      "collectionName": "things",
      "partitionKey": "/things/thingid",
      "connection": "my_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "sqlQuery": "Select * from things s where s.thingid={httpTrigger_body_thingid}"
    }
```

The http Trigger in javascript would look like this in the function, which works: `req.body.thingid`, however binding to the input results in errors, "property not defined" so how do I use an HTTP Trigger input to get a value from a json packet to query cosmos db in the first input, all in the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be just `{thingid}`:

```json
{
  "type": "documentDB",
  "name": "inputDocument",
  "databaseName": "mydb",
  "collectionName": "things",
  "connection": "my_DOCUMENTDB",
  "direction": "in",
  "sqlQuery": "select * from things s where s.thingid={thingid}"
}
```

For a POST request like

```
{
  "thingid": "293a2fc3-799f-4669-92d3-3413f1afa51e"
}
```

it will deliver the documents in `context.bindings.inputDocument` (javascript array).

Comment: helpful, but if I use 
select * from things s where s.thingid={thingid} it never finds the record. That statement seems to bind tightly to the id field of the document, because if I replace just {thingid} with the value of the "id" in my document then the document is located. Also, for the 2nd example "id":"{thingid}" only works if id is the key. My partition was on "thingid".

Comment: I just tested both and it worked for my collection. Second option is indeed for `id` only. I'll remove it.

Comment: yeah, so it won't find the record if the body is as follows { "thingid": 1231}, where 1231 is not in quotes. works fine when in quotes. I'll concede defeat just to move on